# Errorneous Message "No setter found for property" in eclipse kepler with Spring 3.2

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, eclipse-kepler

Got an error in my Spring context file about an not existing setter for property, even it's existing. It's a Spring MVC project and it's compiling and working on my Tomcat.

IMHO it's a Eclipse problem (Eclipse Kepler) + or there seems to be a problem with Maven, which I am using with Eclipse.

Comment: Could u plz share ur code and config files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the issue with eclipse. You can check following things,

1. As it is a maven project the output folder is correct **Java Build Path->Source->Default output folder** is set to <*ProjectName>/target/classes*
2. If your able to build and run it from maven outside the eclipse then try to using same maven installation inside eclipse.
3. You can try run following maven command to refresh the build paths,

   mvn clean install eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse

Answer (score 0):

There's something that i always do with Maven and Eclipse that works more often than not. If you can perform your mvn clean install outside of eclipse, then make sure the same maven is used inside inside Eclipse and then:

1/ project-->Properties-->Maven--> uncheck Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects --> Apply --> OK

2/ project-->Properties-->Maven--> check Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects --> Apply --> OK